# Nuxt 3 tsconfig path is not working from parent directory

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite, tsconfig, nuxtjs3

Following is my directory structure

```
-shared
    --foo.ts
-web-ui (nuxt project)
    --pages
        --index.vue
        --index.ts
    --tsconfig.json
```

My nuxt tsconfig is as below.

```json
{
  // https://v3.nuxtjs.org/concepts/typescript
  "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "~shared/*": ["../shared/*"]
    },
    "rootDirs": [".", "../shared"]
  }
}
```

My nuxt `index.vue` is as below

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome to the homepage {{ foo }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script src="./index.ts" setup lang="ts" />
```

My `index.ts` is as below.

```js
import { useFoo } from '~shared/foo'

const foo = useFoo;
```

I am getting below error.

```
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "~shared/foo" from "pages\index.ts?macro=true". Does the file exist?
C:/Projects/GitLab/legal-disco-typescript/web-ui/pages/index.ts:1:0
1  |  import { useFoo } from "~shared/foo";
   |                          ^
2  |  const foo = useFoo;
3  |
    at formatError (file:///C:/Projects/GitLab/my-project-typescript/web-ui/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-4da11a5e.js:40862:46)
    at TransformContext.error (file:///C:/Projects/GitLab/my-project-typescript/web-ui/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-4da11a5e.js:40858:19)
    at normalizeUrl (file:///C:/Projects/GitLab/my-project-typescript/web-ui/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-4da11a5e.js:37595:33)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async TransformContext.transform (file:///C:/Projects/GitLab/my-project-typescript/web-ui/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-4da11a5e.js:37728:47)
    at async Object.transform (file:///C:/Projects/GitLab/my-project-typescript/web-ui/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-4da11a5e.js:41111:30)
    at async loadAndTransform (file:///C:/Projects/GitLab/my-project-typescript/web-ui/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-4da11a5e.js:37373:29
Click outside or fix the code to dismiss.
You can also disable this overlay by setting server.hmr.overlay to false in vite.config.js.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuxt advises against overriding the path in tsconfig.json in the root of the project

documentation here: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/tsconfig

> note that if you need to customize your paths, this will override the
> auto-generated path aliases. Instead, we recommend that you add any
> path aliases you need to the alias property within your nuxt.config

You need to add it to `nuxt.config.ts`

```
  alias: {
    "~shared": fileURLToPath(new URL("./shared", import.meta.url)),
  },
```

re-run nuxt server and now in your index.ts you can now import `useFoo`

```
import import { useFoo } from '~shared/foo'
```